# Nginx: Restrict access by IP with exception on some routes

Tags: nginx, configuration

I would like to know if it's possible to restrict by IP some ressources:
I want to allow a root pattern to everybody , and I want to restrict all roots to some IP and subnet.

In my nginx conf, I put this:

```
#1 allow pdf files access to all
location ~* /\.pdf$ {
  allow all;
}

#2 restrict to these networks
  allow <ip1>;
  allow <network1>/22;
  allow <network2>/23;

#3 deny all other network
  deny  all;
```

---

When I'm trying to connect from ips different of block #2, I get an access denied.
How could I do to access pdf files from different IP of block #2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine, but the regular expression is wrong. You are currently matching URIs which end with `/.pdf`, but you probably mean to match URIs that end with `.pdf`.

Try:

```
location ~* \.pdf$ {
    allow all;
}
```